# People that rejoice in others' suffering

Tags: single-word-requests, obscure-terms, generic-term, derivational-morphology

I would like to know what terms can be used in English to refer to people that rejoice in other people's suffering (as opposed to empathizing with such people).

What are some of the motivations that would cause people to feel this way? Is it an inborn trait? Is it that people suffer so upon seeing other people suffer they can finally feel equal to others as opposed to feeling less than others?

Comment: Motivations are off-topic, as why someone would behave so does not relate to the English language.

Comment: you could try https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note: the word for the pleasure such people feel is [_Schadenfreude_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude), although this doesn't describe the people themselves.

Comment: I call them "human beings"

Comment: Are you asking about people who get pleasure from _all_ misfortunes suffered by _all_ other people? That seems a highly unusual trait, as opposed to the case where someone has occasional episodes of schadenfreude.

Comment: There is an interesting passage in the biblical book of Proverbs, and it goes, "Do not rejoice when your enemy falls,
And do not let your heart be glad when he stumbles;
Or the Lord will see it and be displeased,
And turn His anger away from him" (24:17-18 NASB). True, the passage is about one's enemies' misfortunes, but it jibes well with Jesus' teaching in the Sermon on the Mount (see Matthew 5:44; cf. Romans 12:2). Don

Comment: Schadenfreud...ist?

Answer (score 18):

Consider **sadist**:

> 1. *Psychiatry.* a person who has the condition of sadism, in which one receives sexual gratification from causing pain and degradation to another.
> 2. a person who enjoys being cruel.

Source: [Dictionary.com](https://dictionary.com/browse/sadist)

Also, **Psychopath**:

> A person suffering from chronic mental disorder with abnormal or violent social behaviour.

Source: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/psychopath)

I think the reasons/motivations are beyond the scope of ELU.

Comment: The question mentions "seeing other people suffer" but says nothing about _causing_ other people to suffer. I think these are two very different things.

Comment: @DavidK maybe 'passive sadism' then. I think sadism does encompass watching people suffer too.

Comment: The dictionary entry you offered doesn't support that interpretation.

Comment: @DavidK what else would you suggest?

Comment: On second thought, I would accept that someone is a sadist if they get pleasure from watching someone else be sadistic without ever performing an act of sadism themselves. I still do not think that sufficiently covers what the question was asking, but honestly I'm not completely sure what the question is. It seems like it _might_ be aiming for schadenfreude, but it also seems like it might be looking for something that would be considered more pathological. So I don't necessarily think this is a bad answer; I meant to say it doesn't quite fit the question, but that may be the question's fault.

Comment: maybe we should ask @JackMaddington to clarify...

Answer (score 14):

Here's an obscure word (and it's a mouthful), because you've added the tags for obscure terms and derived terms:

***Epicaricacist***, formed from *epicaricacy* -- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epicaricacy)

> From Ancient Greek ἐπιχαιρεκακία (epikhairekakía, “joy upon evil”).
>
> *noun* 1. (rare) Rejoicing at or deriving pleasure from the misfortunes of others.
>
> The word is mentioned in some early dictionaries, but **there is little or no evidence of actual usage** until it was picked up by various "interesting word" websites around the turn of the twenty-first century.

*Epicaricacy* is another less popular term for ***schadenfreude***. I think there's also *schadenfreude* + *ist* = ***schadenfreudist***. No real dictionaries have it... yet.

Comment: I think there's also _schadenfreude_ + _ist_ = _schadenfreudist_. No real dictionaries have it... yet.

Comment: schadenfreudians? :-)

Comment: @pgblu That exists, but with a different meaning, on Wiktionary. _(adj.) Relating to, or characterised by schadenfreude_ Link: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schadenfreudian

Comment: The problemi is that evil and suffering are not interchangeable. What if a mother enjoys slapping her kid I the face when they do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is a word *[schadenfreude](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schadenfreude)* borrowing from German *Schadenfreude* (“joy in the misfortune of others”).

There is also a rare word *[schadenfreuder](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schadenfreuder)*, a person experiencing schadenfreude.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I missed. Adding the -r suffix makes more sense.