# Any word or phrase or idiom that describes a person who takes the pleasure from the misfortunes of others?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives, idiom-requests

Is there any word or phrase or idiom that describes **a person who takes the pleasure from the misfortunes of others**?

Comment: Google it: "takes the pleasure from the misfortunes of others," done. Voting to close.

Comment: Related question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43771/an-idiom-for-deriving-pleasure-from-anothers-suffering

Comment: Also related: [People that rejoice in others' suffering](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399792)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Sadomasochist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sadomasochist)** is a person one who derives pleasure by inflicting harm on others

Also, I think **Schadenfreude** can be used.

It means satisfaction or pleasure felt at someone else's misfortune - [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/schadenfreude)

Example: *Still, Clinton aides exulted in **schadenfreude** when their enemies faltered.*

**[Epicaricacy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/13152/epicaricacy)** can also be used.

Comment: Shanmuganthan  I feel your answer doesn't answer what a person for whom 'pleasure is derived by from another person's misfortune' is called. Just now I don't know either. I shall try to find out.

Comment: If you wanted a word for the individual rather than the emotion, "epicaricacist" might do the job. It's offered as an answer to the same question in [this thread](https://wordsmith.org/board/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=135883).

Comment: @Livrecache Edited!

Comment: I think **Schadenfreude** is exactly right in this case. You could use the phrase **malicious glee** though as a possible alternative.